# StyleCop Custom Rules: Method Parameters and Variables

Tags: c#, parameters, stylecop, identifier

I am new to StyleCop, and I need to implement own coding standarts for the place I work. I am using VS2005 and cannot debug it. Upgrading to VS2008/2010 is not an option for us now.

I wonder many things:

1) How can I identify the methods parameters? I tried the below but do not know where to go, SDK documentation is not really helpful.

```
  private bool VisitElement(CsElement element, CsElement parentElement, object context)
        {
            if (element.ElementType == ElementType.Method)
            {
               ...
```

2) How can I find out that a declaration do not follow an assignment? Ex.given.

```
  int i;  // Wrong, give warning
  int i = 0; // True usage
```

3) How can I find out that a document does not contain only 1 namespace or only 1 class inside it and how can I get their identifiers (names)?

True:

```
 namespace Hello 
  {
     class P{

     }
  }
```

-
Wrong:

```
namespace Hi {
  class C {

  } 
  class E {

  }
}  
namespace Ho {
  class D {

  }
}
```

4) How can I find out function calls and find out where to? (i.e. Blocking a call to specific function)

Comment: Which version of StyleCop are you using?

Comment: @Nicole The Latest VS2005 compatible version.

Comment: Could you please provide the version number that you are using?

Comment: Answered, but please try to break multi-part questions like this into separate questions in the future, particularly when the parts are not really related to one another.

Comment: @Nicole, Thanks, I now see the real difference between FxCop and StyleCop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For #1, take a look at the Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.ReadabilityRules.CheckMethodParameters method implementation (either in Reflector or at http://stylecop.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/64d44becb157#Project%2fSrc%2fAddIns%2fCSharp%2fAnalyzers%2fReadabilityRules.MethodParameters.cs).

For #2, something like the following should do the trick:

```
private bool VisitExpression(Expression expression, Expression parentExpression, Statement parentStatement, CsElement parentElement, object context)
{
    if (expression.ExpressionType == ExpressionType.VariableDeclarator)
    {
        VariableDeclaratorExpression declaratorExpression = (VariableDeclaratorExpression)expression;
        if (declaratorExpression.Initializer == null)
        {
            this.AddViolation(parentElement, expression.LineNumber, "YourRule", declaratorExpression.Identifier.Text);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The existing SA1402 (FileMayOnlyContainASingleClass) and SA1403 (FileMayOnlyContainASingleNamespace) rules should take care of #3.  If they don't work for your scenario, please specify what you would like a custom rule to do differently.

#4 should be an FxCop rule, not a StyleCop rule since it has nothing to do with source code style.